# Uninstall methods in Android

Tags: android, list, batch-file, uninstallation

Hey everybody, I was wondering where, or what is the methods used in the batch uninstaller programs? I know how to pull up lists of the applications, and the icons in a listview.. getting them into the right lists and whatever, but how do I actually uninstall the application? Thanksa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just passing the delete intent is what I was looking for